# Drodown list return issue

Tags: javascript, tags, dropdown, list

I made a function that doesn't work properly: it correctly returns the slug of the selected tags except the first one in the list.
Someone can help me understand why please?
The code is below ...
Thank you

=============================================

```
<select>
<option value="" disabled selected>-- choose --</option>
<?php $select = wp_dropdown_categories(array('taxonomy'=>'post_tag', 'value_field' => 'slug', 'show_count'=>1, 'orderby'=>'name', 'echo'=>0)); ?>
<option value="<?php echo $select; ?></option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

$('select').on(‘click’, function() {

var selection = $(this).val();

location.href = 'http://www.example.com/tag/' + selection;

});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Please try **onchange** event instead of **onclick**.

Comment: Hello Pratik, thanks for your suggest but unfortunately is the same also modifying the event.